# How to calculate euclidean distance between 2D and 3D tensors in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Given:

- a tensor A has shape `(batch_size, dim)`
- a tensor B has shape `(batch_size, N, dim)`

I want to calculate euclidean distance between each row in A and the correspond row in B which has shape `(N, dim)`

The expected result has shape `(batch_size, N)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`torch.cdist`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cdist.html):

```
>>> torch.cdist(A[:,None],B)
```

Comment: does it do broadcast in the last dimension?

Comment: Yes, the `A[:,None]` allows to unsqueeze a singleton dimension at `dim=1` which is automatically broadcasted to match `B`'s size (equal to `N`).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one; it helped me, and it may also resolve your problem.

```
import numpy as np
def euclidean_distance(A, B):

A_expanded = np.expand_dims(A, axis=1)

squared_diff = np.square(A_expanded - B)

squared_distance = np.sum(squared_diff, axis=-1)

euclidean_distance = np.sqrt(squared_distance)

return euclidean_distance

batch_size = 3
N = 4
dim = 2

# Generate sample data
A = np.random.rand(batch_size, dim)
B = np.random.rand(batch_size, N, dim)

# Calculate Euclidean distance
distances = euclidean_distance(A, B)
print(distances)
```